# Covering a former service panel turned junction box

Tags: electrical-panel, code-compliance, junction-box

This is in Colorado, United States.

Having some remodeling ongoing, I've had a contractor upgrade my existing electrical service panel, a 100-A Cutler-Hammer, with a new Square D 200-A panel on the opposite (exterior) wall. I'm left with what is now a large junction box covered with the existing Cutler-Hammer panelboard cover.

[image: Covered panel]
[image: Panel, without cover]

What can I do to make this less unattractive/conspicuous while remaining compliant with code/regulations? I know the junction box must remain accessible, but are there plain covers without doors that exist for this purpose? Maybe a cover for the cover? Is painting the existing cover the best I can do?

I did do some searches for this but was unable to find anything relevant. I'm hopeful that I'm bad at searching and there's a solution for this out there.

Comment: Hang a flat white LED light panel over it and put a curtain in front - pretend it's a window.

Comment: How high off the ground is it?   Thinking about keeping it safe from kids.  It its at waist height needs more protection than if its above head height.

Comment: @Criggie if it was above head height then it would have been invalid as a panel location.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hang a nice picture over it. Easy. Cheap. No inspector can complain.

Comment: LOL, I was going to say the same thing. Also, looks like the electrician did a good job.

Comment: Do think keeping it accessible(less than a minute) is the main thing.  Screwing a piece of plywood over it is a no-no, placing a non-locking internal door in a frame over it is okay.

Comment: Also, paint it to match the wall.

Comment: @crip659  I don't understand why it would need to accessible in under a minute? There are no disconnects there.   I agree screwing a piece of plywood over it could be interpreted as non accessible. But hanging a picture over it should be OK.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Think they want you to access it faster than unscrewing something, so a picture or door or even a chair/sofa that can be toss out of the way be okay.

Comment: It doesn't have to be accessible fast.  It has to be FINDABLE, AT ALL, *without prior knowledge* of the building.  Fast forward, the room has been painted 3 times, there is no way to get that cover off without making a mess.  The electrician suspects a mystery junction box somewhere. Do you *Really* want them unscrewing every such panel in the house?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  How many panels like this do you expect to find in a house? "unscrewing every such panel..."??????

Comment: So write a clear label and stick it inside the master panel, perhaps "NOTE Junction box is in wall 5 metres south of this cabinet, behind picture frame 2021-11-08 "   Future electrician will be grateful.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson You don't want to give the electrician the idea that he now has to look for hidden panels. The actual number is irrelevant, because he's now wasting time finding them.

Comment: @crip659 Except for breaker boxes which have a latch for a door that swings open as part of a panel that is screwed down, don't _all_ junction boxes have some sort of cover that is screwed in place? If unscrewing a cover makes it non compliant, _looks at the light switch cover plate on the wall_ then I think we're all in trouble...

Comment: @FreeMan There is a difference between a cover that is part of the normal installation (breaker panel cover, light switch cover) and an arbitrary thing covering it up. Plus there is definitely a difference between sheet metal screws designed to be easily removed/replaced (like a light switch cover) and wood screws through the corners of a sheet of plywood into studs.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, I assume you mean machine screws. A sheet metal screw is much more similar to a wood screw.

Comment: Oops! You're correct. I meant machine screws. The nice straight kind that are not designed to "bite" into anything.

Answer (score 8):

### Cabinet door

A cabinet door/frame can be used to provide camouflage for the existing ex-loadcenter door, provided it doesn't block access to the inside of the cabinet-turned-junction-box.

Comment: Yup, and Victorian houses are full of cabinet doors into utility spaces. My last two houses had cabinet doors giving access to the backside of the tub faucet, easy faucet changes!  Note that the former panel needs to have proper blanking plates, there can't be gaping holes where breakers once were.  Either use listed blanking plates from Cutler Hammer/Eaton (be clear on BR vs CH), or get your AHJ to approve a sheetmetal/pop-rivet deal. Good thing you can walk the cover into the AHJ's office and just ask them.

Comment: One could also screw the door shut provided the loadcenter cover can still be removed

Answer (score 6):

## Paint it

Cheap and easy solution that makes it surprisingly less visible. If you have any spare wall paint somewhere this might even cost you nothing.

If that's not terribly appealing, painting something decorative onto the door can make it look like a wall decoration.